# calculating select distinct with web service using PHP

Tags: php, json, rest

I have a problem with select distinct and calculate my data. I am on restful web service server side. And I made service like this :

```
private function grafik()
        {
            if($this->get_request_method() !="GET") 
                {
                    $this->response('',406);
                }
                    $sql   = "select distinct operating_system from data";
                    $query = $this->mysqli->query($sql) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);
                    //$query = mysql_query( $sql )  or die(mysql_error());
                    while( $ret = $query->fetch_array() ){

                    $os=$ret['operating_system'];

                    $sql_jumlah   = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE operating_system='$os'";  
                    $query_jumlah = $this->mysqli->query($sql_jumlah) or die($this->mysqli->error.__LINE__);

                         $data = mysqli_num_rows( $query_jumlah );
                            $jumlah = $mydata;
echo $jumlah;   
echo $os;
```

The problem is I'm really confused on how I can get `$jumlah` and `$os` on different variable into client side with

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/proejct/services/server');
```

When i `echo $json`, I get both of `$jumlah` and `$os` on `$json`, but I want to get that in 2 different variables.  What should I do?

Comment: Injection vulnerability spotted (again)

Comment: excusme?? sorry if i make a mistake

Comment: Google injection attacks, and prepared statements. Bottom line: if the value of `$os` contains a single quote, or a backslash at the end, your secondary query will fail, or possibly result in data corruption. With an OS called `DOS'; DROP TABLE data; -- `, for example, you'd loose all your data. PS: methods should never echo, they should `return` data, letting the user (whoever calls the method) decide where the data is going to next (echo, or write to logs, or whatever)

Comment: yes you right elias, im new one of this..,i got it :(

Comment: No worries, we've all made mistakes while learning... I'm sorry if I seemed arrogant or hostile.

Comment: Basically: `return array('os' => $os, 'jumlah' => $jumlah);`, use an array, extract each value, assign to separate variables, or echo `json_encode($theArray);` into JS code you might be churning out

Comment: no,of course you're right.., you make me learn something. i need to protect what i made from sql injection of course. then do u know what should i do for my question over there?? i want to use that data on pie chart js.., so i need two variable $os and $jumlah for data count

Comment: Cf last comment: PHP to JS communication is easiest done through JSON. pass a JSON-encoded string. `var phpVals = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;`, then you have a JS object, allowing you to access the values like so: `phpVals.os` and `phpVals.jumlah`

Comment: okey im gonna try this now, ill be back to comment again :) really thanks for your feedback.. elias,

Comment: isnt working yet, i think it cant be only get the value by get the variable on encoding, because there is two query in one function web service,its simply if i just one to get $os variable on database, but confusing is i want count how much $os on database and print it, to get count $os its little bit confusing :( *sorry im new one of this